# About Basic CSS classes and hierarchy - not to effect all page elements

Tags: css, styles, stylesheet

I have the following sample doing what I want:

```
<style>
div { position: relative; padding-top: 30px; display: block; }
div h3 { position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: block; }
div h3 a { width: 200px; height: 230px; display: block; }
div img { width: 200px; height: 200px; display: block; }
</style>

<div>
 <h3><a href="/xxxx/abcd.htm">linker</a></h3>
 <img src="/xxxx/abcd.jpg" alt="linker image" />
</div>
```

The obvious problem is that it affects all of the items on page and not only the needed div.
How do I put it into proper class formation without losing the hierarchy and having it not affecting all of the page's elements.

Thanks

Comment: If you found any answer please mark it as accepted . Then it will help others.....

Answer (score 0):

Use `class`es and `ID`s. They are used to solve your problem - distinguish elements. `ID`s need to be unique in your whole document while `class`es can occure multiple times. Also one element can have several classes (whitespace separated list) but only one ID.

```
<div id="unique-id" class="class1 class2 class2">    
    <h3 class="child-h3"><a href="/xxxx/abcd.htm">linker</a></h3>
</div>
```

and in css:

```
#unique-id{
   ...styles
}

#unique-id h3,
#unique-id child-h3{ /* both selectors will match the same element*/
    ...styles
}

.class1{
   ...styles
}
```

you can find a short tutorial here: http://www.tizag.com/cssT/cssid.php

also, you might want to look into **selectors**: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html

Answer (score 0):

read more about descendant selectors in css: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors

Comment: How does this answer the question? There is not even a `p` element in the example code.

Answer (score -1):

This is the better and simple way..

```
<style>
.div { position: relative; padding-top: 30px; display: block; }
.div h3 { position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: block; }
.div h3 a { width: 200px; height: 230px; display: block; }
.div img { width: 200px; height: 200px; display: block; }
</style>

<div class='div'>
 <h3><a href="/xxxx/abcd.htm">linker</a></h3>
 <img src="/xxxx/abcd.jpg" alt="linker image" />
</div>
```

Comment: `<div>` with `class="div"`, seriously? And what if he would decide to use eg `<article>` instead of `<div>`?

Comment: He can use  <article class="div">   instead of <div class="div">  here div is just the name ...

Comment: Great idea. Just like making class `.red` with rules `{color: blue}`.

Comment: @ogur I just given sample name for class. you can give any name instead of div for css class. .class1 , like this. I dont think that's a big mistake here